# Swift - Insert UIView and animate it to XY Co-ordinates within a UIScrollView

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, autolayout, transform

I'm trying to animate an inserted subView from the pressed grid number (Number 1) to the top row (position B - See image).

I've managed to move the UIView's X Y but I can't seem to find out how to move it from A to B without using CGPoints/CGFloats.

I've tried assigning CGFlaots to the positionAViewbounds.origin.x & positionAViewbounds.origin.y but it only moves relative to the superview and not the entire window view

Here is my code so far:

```
        UIView.animateWithDuration(
         0.350, delay: 0, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.850, initialSpringVelocity: 10.0, options: [], animations: {


            self.yellowSquare.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(50, -50)


            }, completion:nil)
```

[image: Here is a screen shot]

***UPDATE:***

So I've managed to get it kind of working by using 'convertPoint'
The only problem I can't figure out is that it's only working when I press the UIButton for the second time.

**On first press the co-ordinates are:**

Yellow coord = -16.5

Yellow coord = 288.0

**and on second press the co-ordinates are:**

Yellow coord = 24.0

Yellow coord = 18.0

Here is my code so far:

```
// Inserting Yellow UIView
func createYellowSquare() {
    self.yellowSquare.frame = ballEmptyR1B1.frame //Define size of UiView
    self.yellowSquare.backgroundColor = colorYellow //Set colors
    self.numberGrid1.insertSubview(yellowSquare, aboveSubview: numberGrid1) //Insert Yellow Square
}


// Animate the ball pressed number to empty slot
func animateBalls() {

UIView.animateWithDuration(
    0.200, delay: 0, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.950, initialSpringVelocity: 5.0, options: [], animations: {

        //Convert the center points 
        let yellowUIViewCoordinates = self.yellowSquare.convertPoint(self.yellowSquare.center, toView: self.ballEmptyR1B1)
        print("Yellow coord = \(yellowUIViewCoordinates.x)")
        print("Yellow coord = \(yellowUIViewCoordinates.y)")

        //CGAffine Transform to new x y co-ordinates
        self.yellowSquare.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(yellowUIViewCoordinates.x - 24, yellowUIViewCoordinates.y - 18)//Move to new center point

    }, completion: { _ in
            self.yellowSquare.removeFromSuperview() // Remove YellowUIView after animation is complete

            self.ballEmptyR1B1.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0.5, 0.5); //Scale UIView 0.5
            self.selectedNumberR1B1.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0.5, 0.5); //Scale UIView 0.5

            UIView.animateWithDuration(
                0.450, delay: 0.0, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.450, initialSpringVelocity: 15.0, options: [], animations: {
                    self.ballEmptyR1B1.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.0, 1.0); //Scale UIView 1.0
                    self.selectedNumberR1B1.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.0, 1.0); //Scale UIView 1.0
                },  completion:nil)
        }
        )
```

And here is a gif rec. in slo-mo to give better context to what I am refering to:

[Animated GIF of Interface](https://i.stack.imgur.com/37fZg.gif)

Comment: Inside the scrollView you want to animate two buttons which has constraints yes?

Comment: When you press "1" (with the red dashed border):

Yellow UIView is created and inserted ontop of the "1" in the fixed view

I then apply a " UIView.animateWithDuration" on the newly created YellowUIView


Basically I want to tell the yellowUIview to move/animate from it's point of creation to the co-ordinates witin the scrollView (position B) without specifying relative integer XY co-ordinates